# Windows phone custom user control with template support

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am making a custom user control and I want the control to be reusable and a part of the control to be usable for adding new controls. What I am trying to make is a template in the custom user control in which the user can add new content.

I am using windows phone 8

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add new Templated Control from "Add new item" menu.
You should get `Generic.xaml` file in `Themes` folder.

In `Generic.xaml` you  have style for your custom control:

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
                Write your control xaml here
                <Border x:Name="BorderNameTest"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Button IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsFancyLookEnabled}"></Button>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You'll also have `.cs` file for your custom control. To use controls (in code) from your custom control template xaml you need to use `[TemplatePart]` attribute on your "control class".
Snippet:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = BorderTestTemplatePartName, Type = typeof(Border))]
public sealed class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    private const string BorderTestTemplatePartName = "BorderNameTest";
    private Border _myBorder;

   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFancyLookEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsFancyLookEnabled", typeof (bool), typeof (CustomControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    public bool IsFancyLookEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsFancyLookEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsFancyLookEnabledProperty, value); }
    } 

    public CustomControl1()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _myBorder = GetTemplateChild(BorderTestTemplatePartName) as Border;

        // attach events etc. (you can detach them using for example Unloaded event)

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

Additionaly I have shown you how to expose properties on your control (so your control user can write `<namespace:SuperControl IsFancyLookEnabled="True">`). You create dependency property (as shown in code snippet) which you can use in your xaml with `TemplateBinding` - or just use in code.